# Keras CNN with 1D data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Every instance of my data is an array with 72 elements. I am trying to construct a 1D cnn to do some classification but I got this error:
Error when checking target: expected dense_31 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (3560, 1)

This is my code:

```
training_features = np.load('features.npy')
training_labels = np.load('labels.npy')
training_features = training_features.reshape(-1, 72, 1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(72, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(28, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_features, training_labels, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.1)
```

I am a beginner. Sorry if I have poor understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether your inputs in correct form. Can you share the two *.npy files (or at least shapes of your inputs).

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, Dense, MaxPooling1D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(72, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(28, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model.fit(training_features, training_labels, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.1)

model.summary()

Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_7 (Conv1D)            (None, 70, 64)            256       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_6 (MaxPooling1 (None, 35, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_8 (Conv1D)            (None, 33, 64)            12352     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_7 (MaxPooling1 (None, 16, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 64)                65600     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 28)                1820      
=================================================================
Total params: 80,028
Trainable params: 80,028
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help! The shape of training_features is (3560, 72, 1).

Comment: what about shape of labels

Comment: The shape of training_labels is (3560,)

Comment: Please use `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`

Comment: Hell yeah, it works! Thank you! Could you tell me what mistake have I made?

Comment: Your y_true is of size (3560,) and your predicted y_pred is (3560, 28). So there is a mismatch. `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` will take care of it under the hood. Please upvote if my answer was helpful to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you start with a three dimensional layer but never reduce the dimensionality in any of the following layers.
Try adding `model.add(Flatten())` before the first Dense layer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I get this error:
Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (28,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: My data isn't really an image. Each instance is an array of 72 elements. How should I configure the input shape?