# input_shape of Conv1D layer Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to make a CNN model for binary classification of a non-image dataset. My model/ code is working and producing very good results (accuracies are high) but I am unable to understand the `input_shape` parameter for the 1st layer of `Conv1D`.

The shape of X or input (here `x_train_df`) is (2000, 28). It has 28 features and 2000 samples. And the shape of Y or labels (here `y_train_df`) is (2000, 1).

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (x_train_df.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

optimzr = Adam(learning_rate=0.005)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimzr,  metrics=[[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(curve="ROC", name = 'auc')], [tf.keras.metrics.AUC(curve="PR", name = 'pr')]])

# running the fitting
model.fit(x_train_df, y_train_df, epochs = 2, batch_size = 32, validation_data = (x_val_df, y_val_df), verbose = 2)
```

I have given `input_shape` as (28, 1) (taken reference from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030068/keras-cnn-with-1d-data)).

But in [Conv1D layer documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/) it is written that,

> When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide an
> input_shape argument (tuple of integers or None, e.g. (10, 128) for
> sequences of **10 vectors of 128-dimensional vectors**.

What I understood from this is the dimension of input_shape should be (2000, 1) as I have 2000 one-dimensional vectors. But giving this as `input_shape` shows an error as,

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_25" is incompatible with the
> layer: expected shape=(None, 2000, 1), found shape=(None, 28)

**So my question is what should be the correct `input_shape`?**

Comment: can you tell what is your dataset shape for input_shape (2000,1)?

Comment: if your dataset shape is (2000, 1)=(batch_size, row) that is incorrect to the input_shape(2000, 1). so, the dataset must be shaped (batch_size, 2000, 1).

Comment: The shape of my original input is (2000, 28). Making it (1, 2000, 28) assuming batch size of 1 showed error. Please see the comment on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check how "Conv1D" takes input.

```
>>> # The inputs are 128-length vectors with 10 timesteps, and the batch size
>>> # is 4.
>>> input_shape = (4, 10, 128)
>>> x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
>>> y = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(
... 32, 3, activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x)
>>> print(y.shape)
    (4, 8, 32)
```

> 3+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)

[As seen above](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/), there are 128 features, 10 timesteps and batch size of 4. So, Conv1D takes input as (batch_size,timesteps,features). It takes 3D input. Let's say you choose batch size as 1 for your case. You have to give input like (1,2000,28).

Comment: Making the input as (1,2000,28) made an error as `ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape, received ((None, 1) vs (None, 2000)).` So I changed the shapes to be (2000, 28, 1) for `x_train_df` and (2000, 1, 1) for `y_train_df` as shown [in this](https://www.kaggle.com/isaienkov/1d-convolutional-neural-network-starter) and that worked. I am confused about this. It will be very helpful if you could explain how to modify the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I use CNN-Conv1D for non-image dataset too. I have 188 features. So I doing this to my  input :
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1],1))

#in my initialing RNN

model.add(Reshape((188, 1), input_shape(X_train[1], 1))

so the input shape (None, 188, 1)

and it's work for me ,I got 97 % of training and 91 % for testing the data with real data.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this trying to implement Wavenet, where the audio feature is a single-dimensional array of audio samples. Sample code giving this error:

```
x = tf.keras.Input((64000,), BATCH_SIZE)
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(1, 1)(x)
model = Model(x, y)
```

`x.shape` here is `(BATCH_SIZE,64000)` or in my case `(100,64000)`

The error message indicated that `min_ndim=3` but `ndim=2`.

I resolved this by appending a `1` to the input layer's shape:

```
x = tf.keras.Input((64000,1,), BATCH_SIZE)
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(1, 1)(x)
model = Model(x, y)
```

Now the shape of `x` is `(100,64000,1)` which the `Conv1D` eats up.

This reflects the perspective of an audio sample as equivalent to a single "channel" (comparing to a computer vision context.) And thus, by pretending your audio data is really monochrome image data, the Tensorflow gods are appeased, bringing a good harvest of scrumptious metrics through all the cycles of time.